# fnServerParams is not a function

Tags: ajax, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and I want to add parameter to Ajax call in my table definition.

But it gives error when I attempt to use `fnServerParams`. Here is my table and method that I use to add parameter:

```js
var tableObjects = $("#logTable").DataTable({
        "bProcessing": false,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "../../Controller/DashboardController.php5",
        "aoColumns": [
            {"mDataProp": "clientname" ,"sortable": false },
            {"mDataProp": "clientip"},
            {"mDataProp": "url","sortable": false },
            {"mDataProp": "respsize"},
            {"mDataProp": "loggingdate"},
            {"mDataProp": "reqmethod"},
            {"mDataProp": "resultcode"},
            {"mDataProp": "duration"},
            {"mDataProp": "hierarchycode"}
        ],
        "fnServerParams": function (val1,val2 ) {
            if((val1)&&(val2))
                aoData.push({"name":val1,value:val2})
        },
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
            aoData.push({"name":"tablename","value":"dashboard"});
            $.ajax({
                "dataType": "json",
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "type": "GET",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": function(result){
                    fnCallback(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, error){
                    }
                }
            });
        }
})
```

And I add parameters with this function call:

```js
$("#slcFilter").on("change",function(){
   tableObjects.fnServerParams("paramname","value");
   //"tableObjects.fnServerParams is not a function" but why ?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In DataTables 1.10 naming convention has changed, see [API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) for more information.

You need to initialize your table as `$("#logTable").dataTable()` with lower case `d` to get access to previous version API or with `$("#logTable").DataTable()` with upper case `D` to get access to newer API.

Also there is no `fnServerParams()` function, it's an option [`fnServerParams`](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnServerParams) that should be defined as follows:

```js
"fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
    aoData.push( { "name": "select", "value": $("#slcFilter").val() } );      
},
```

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33212925/3549014) to your other similar question.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation is also a little bit vague on this issue, I think.

Comment: @davidkonrad, yes, I agree. Many examples on the web site still use `dataTable()` which is somewhat confusing.

Comment: And SO (stackoverflow) should implement some kind of version tagging system.  There is many, many libraries where you are googling and find "wrong" answers because the answer is about an earlier version of a library. I have long thought about suggesting this, but I cannot figure out how to express my thoughts precisely. I fear I just get downvotes and the typical meta llame answer as "just retag" or similar. But it is an increasing "problem". People are googling for answers, and they meet a correct answer, but to an obsoluted version of the code they are using.

Comment: @davidkonrad, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865, is this what you're talking about?